# How to plot pandas kde with a horizontal orientation

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, kernel-density

Pandas offers `kind='kde'` when plotting. In my setting, I would prefer a kde density. The alternative `kind='histogram'` offers the orientation option: `orientation='horizontal'`, which is strictly necessary for what I am doing. Unfortunately, `orientation` is not available for kde.

At least this is what I think that happens because I get a

```
in set_lineprops
    raise TypeError('There is no line property "%s"' % key)
TypeError: There is no line property "orientation"
```

Is there any straight forward alternative for plotting *kde* horizontally as easily as it can be done for *histogram*?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

plt.ion()

ser = pd.Series(np.random.random(1000))
ax1 = plt.subplot(2,2,1)
ser.plot(ax = ax1, kind = 'hist')
ax2 = plt.subplot(2,2,2)
ser.plot(ax = ax2, kind = 'kde')
ax3 = plt.subplot(2,2,3)
ser.plot(ax = ax3, kind = 'hist', orientation = 'horizontal')

# not working lines below
ax4 = plt.subplot(2,2,4)
ser.plot(ax = ax4, kind = 'kde', orientation = 'horizontal')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- Adding previously deleted answer as a community wiki because it's a helpful answer.
- [`pandas.Series.plot.kde`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.kde.html) does not have an option to change the orientation of the plot.
- Use [`scipy.stats.gaussian_kde`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) to calculate the values, and plot them on a line with [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html).
- Alternatively, [`seaborn.kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) is an option.
- `gaussian_kde` is used under the hood by both `.plot.kde` and `sns.kdeplot`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

# crate subplots and don't share x and y axis ranges
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 10), sharex=False, sharey=False)

# flatten the axes for easy selection from a 1d array
axes = axes.flat

# create sample data
np.random.seed(2022)
ser = pd.Series(np.random.random(1000)).sort_values()

# plot example plots
ser.plot(ax=axes[0], kind='hist', ec='k')
ser.plot(ax=axes[1], kind='kde')
ser.plot(ax=axes[2], kind='hist', orientation='horizontal', ec='k')

# 1. create kde model
gkde = gaussian_kde(ser)

# 2. create a linspace to match the range over which the kde model is plotted
xmin, xmax = ax2.get_xlim()
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 1000)

# 3. plot the values
axes[3].plot(gkde(x), x)

# Alternatively, use seaborn.kdeplot and skip 1., 2., and 3.
# sns.kdeplot(y=ser, ax=axes[3])
```

[image]